# DolphinDB - convert matrix to table and vice versa with column names retained

Tags: dolphindb

How can I keep the column names when transforming between matrix and table in DolphinDB?

The `matrix` function creates a matrix from a table without the field.

Any straight ways to convert between the data forms?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following functions to conduct conversion:

```
a = table(2020.01.01..2020.01.05 as date1, 1..5 as price, 6..10 as vol)
b = matrix(a[,1:]).rename!(a.date1,a.colNames()[1:])
c = table(b.rowNames() as date1,b)
```